# I'm trying to use stoi(), but the compiler is trying to give me replacements and won't compile

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm just practicing my C++ through HackerRanks, and I'm doing this problem:

> **Problem Statement**
>
> You are given an integer N. Find the digits in this number that
>   exactly divide N(division that leaves 0 as remainder) and display
>   their count. For N=24, there are 2 digits − 2 & 4. Both of these
>   digits exactly divide 24. So our answer is 2.
>
> **Note**
>
> If the same number is repeated twice at different positions, it should
>   be counted twice, e.g., For N=122, 2 divides 122 exactly and occurs at
>   ones' and tens' position. So for this case, our answer is 3. Division
>   by 0 is undefined. Input Format
>
> The first line contains T (number of test cases) followed by T lines
>   (each containing an integer N).
>
> **Constraints**  1≤T≤15  0

This is my program:

```
    1 #include <cmath>
    2 #include <string>
    3 #include <iostream>
    4 #include <cstdlib>
    5 using namespace std;
    6 void checkDigits(string);
    7 int main (){
    8   string val;
    9   int count = 0, i;
   10
   11   cin >> i;
   12   for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
   13     cin >> val;
   14     checkDigits(val);
   15   }
   16   return 0;
   17 }
   18
   19 void checkDigits(string s){
   20   int len, count = 0;
   21   int full, digit;
   22
   23   len = s.length();
   24   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   25     full = stoi(s);
   26     digit = stoi(s[i]);
   27     if(full % digit == 0)
   28       count++;
   29   }
   30   cout << count;
   31 }
```

What would cause my compiler to give me this error?

> hackerrank2.cpp: In function ‘void checkDigits(std::string)’:
>   hackerrank2.cpp:26:20: error: call of overloaded ‘stoi(char&)’ is
>   ambiguous    digit = stoi(s[i]);
>                       ^ hackerrank2.cpp:26:20: note: candidates are: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
>                    from hackerrank2.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2823:3: note: int
>   std::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int)     stoi(const
>   string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)    ^
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2823:3: note:   no known
>   conversion for argument 1 from ‘char’ to ‘const string& {aka const
>   std::basic_string&}’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2926:3: note: int
>   std::stoi(const wstring&, std::size_t*, int) 
>   stoi(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)    ^
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2926:3: note:   no known
>   conversion for argument 1 from ‘char’ to ‘const wstring& {aka const
>   std::basic_string&}’

Answer (score 8):

`std::stoi()` works on strings, not characters; there is no overload of `std::stoi()` that accepts `char`, and this is what the compiler is telling you. (Note that the prototypes listed take `const std::string &` and `const std::wstring &` as their respective first arguments. `char &` is not implicitly convertible to either of these and so the compiler can't pick which overload it should use since neither will work.)

If you know that the character is a digit then you can can use this simple function:

```
inline int ctoi(char c)
{
    return c - '0';
}
```

(Or just do it inline: `digit = s[i] - '0';`)